# AJAX request returning JSON?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, json

So I'm using AJAX to scrape player names and their respective ratings from a site.  I have AJAX return a JSON object and I'm trying to use jQuery to append each element of the JSON object as a list item in an ordered list.

Here's the code:

```
$('#rankings_link').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/rankings',
        type: 'get'
    }).done(function(received_data){
        for (var m = 0; m < received_data.length; m++) {
            $('#rankings ol').append('<li>' + received_data[m] + '</li>');
  }
```

But when I look at my localhost:3000/rankings page, it's just one large array of player names (correctly ordered) but not formatted as a list at all.

What's going on here?

Thanks in advance,
Mariogs

Comment: Post that _large array_ here.

Comment: You are missing the closing `})`'s from the `don` and `click` functions. Was that just an error putting it into Stack Overflow? I doubt that's the cause of your problems, but it is a problem!

Comment: `/rankings` is your service where you get the json from right? why would you navigate directly to it expecting a formatted list?

Comment: What does this have to do with Ruby and Rails?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp

I would use eval to get you json string into an object you can loop an array through

```
var rankings = eval ("(" + received_data + ")");

for (var m = 0; m < rankings.length; m++) {
        $('#rankings ol').append('<li>' + rankings[m].(whatever piece of data you want from your json object) + '</li>');
```

}

If you are still having trouble show me what your json string looks like.

Comment: Or, you know, you could use the built-in json parser `JSON.parse(received_data)` (with json2.js as backup) or, since jQuery is included, use it's parser which is implemented the same way. `$.parseJSON(received_data)`. Oh wait, we're using `$.ajax` and `dataType:"json"`, so jQuery has already done that for us.

Comment: please refrain from linking w3schools as a resource.. more info here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource

Comment: So I still haven't been able to get it to work :( for what it's worth, my "/rankings" page doesn't even show that I have a #rankings id or the <ol> tag when I view source...

Answer (score 0):

I would use a $.each loop to sort thru the received data. The json object is an unordered set of key/value pairs. When you use a $.each loop you can separate those out and utilize the value(player info) which is what you are looking for. Like this:

```
$('#rankings_link').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/rankings',
        type: 'get'
    }).done(function(received_data){
        $.each(received_data, function(index, player){
            $('#rankings ol').append('<li>' + player + '</li>');
        });
    });
 });
```